# how to get the string literal of an objects name from the full path

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a list of objects

```
AList = [txnjan,txnfeb, txnmarch...txmarch,txnmarch]
```

when I do

```
ALIst.each{ println it}
```

I get

```
class summ.txnjan, class summ.txnfeb
```

...
when I print out

```
it.name
```

I get

```
summ.txnjan, summ.txnfeb...etc
```

how do I just get the string literal of the class name no package pre-appended like

```
'txnjan', 'txnfeb', 'txnmarch'
```

..etc, I want to use this in a HQL query..

is there an easier way?or do a

```
string.split("\\.")
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getSimpleName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29):

```
def types = [String, Integer, List, Boolean]

types.each { println it.simpleName }
```

Otput:

```
String
Integer
List
Boolean
```

BTW, it's pretty confusing to use lowercase names for types and upper camel case names for variables (e.g. `AList`) in Java's world, where naming conventions are quite strong. Try using upper camel case for types and lower camel case for variables :)